# Apache returns 502 Bad Gateway with mod_proxy and large file

Tags: apache, proxy, mod-proxy

I am seeing a problem when sending a file through Apache configured as proxy to a local application using the Mongoose webserver.

My setup:

> Apache (port 80) <-> mod_proxy <-> Mongoose (port 9090)

mod_proxy is configured to transfer certain URLs from port 80 to localhost:9090.

Mongoose only accepts authenticated responses. This works OK for normal (small) requests. With large file transfers however Apache returns a 502 Bad Gateway response.

What happens (well, actually just my analysis of what happens) is that when our client (a .net client, expect 100 enabled) tries to send a file it sends the headers followed directly by the contents of the file.

Mongoose receives the headers of the transfer, detects that it is not authenticated and returns a 401 Unauthorized and closes the connection. Now Apache (which is still receiving and processing the file transfer)  cannot forward the data any more and returns a 502 Bad Gateway (The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server).

When sniffing on the external interface I see that the .net client sends the headers, followed within 20 msec by the contents, without receiving a 100 Continue. When the receive is finished Apache returns the 502.

When sniffing the internal interface I see that the header and body are combined into one tcp packet of 16384 bytes. Mongoose replies within a few msecs with the 401 and closes the connection.

It looks like Apache detects the close of the connection but ignores the 401 and does not forward this. Is there a possibility to have Apache correctly forward the 401 instead of replying with the 502?

For the moment I changed our application to just read all data from the connection if a 401 is detected, but this is just a workaround as this comes down to sending the complete file twice. As the files can be hundreds of megabytes this can give quite some stress on our system.

We are using Apache 2.2.9 (Debian) on an ARM system.

Answer (score 4):

You are probably experiencing the Apache bug filed here https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55433

Related links:

- http://osdir.com/ml/bugs-httpd/2013-08/msg00119.html
- http://osdir.com/ml/bugs-httpd/2013-08/msg00094.html
- http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-users/msg04580.html

PS: I've hit the same issue, and it's rather an obscure bug (both to find info on it, and the bug itself). FWIW, nginx does not present the same behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for giving this answer. I had the same issue and indeed the Jetty, providing the actual response, did reply with a 401, which got translated by Apache to a 502.

Comment: @d'Scribe this bug has been reported since 2013 (probably existed for many years before that), and it is still not fixed. Your options are limited and converge towards switching to another reverse proxy e.g. nginx.